# Error SQLSTATE al crear una tabla mediante codigo

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola a todos soy muy nuevo en codigo y estoy practicando con un codigo abierto que encontre, estoy usando PHP con Bootstrap y Admin LTE y para una sección de productos no me crea datos para la tabla si funciona el boton para crear nuevo producto te pide las indicaciones de datos para cada tabla pero causa falla al momento de agregar, si yo inserto los datos desde phpmyadmin si me deja crear y lo muestra en la tabla pero en el portal me genera un error y no se que datos mas tenga que compartir para que me ayuden, todas las tablas funcionan menos la de crear productos

[image: img de error]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Tu **tabla** tiene un número de columnas que no coincide con el número de valores que estás pasando en el **controlador**. Ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327233/insert-value-list-does-not-match-column-list-1136-column-count-doesnt-match-va

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico  Muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya resolvi el problema me ayudaste mucho te lo agradezco mucho ahora tengo un error en el boton de editar pero primero vere si puedo yo solo gracias por tu compartir de tu conocimiento